# Почему появляется ошибка TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
d = r.json
print(d['id'])
```

почему появляется ошибка:
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

спасибо

Comment: Потому что `r.json` это метод, который надо вызвать, а вы не вызываете

Answer (score 1):

Вам оставил **andreymal** исчерпывающий комментарий.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
d = r.json()
for data in d:
    print(data['id'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Поясню слова @andreymal:

**requests.get()** возвращает объект **requests.models.Response**, у которого есть **метод** json(). Не вызвав этот метод, вы в переменную **d** получаете **ссылку** на этот метод, а не результат его работы. Для того чтобы получить результат его выполнения, его нужно вызвать.
Т.е. в вашем случае это должно быть так:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
d = r.json
print(d()['id'])
```

Но правильнее, все же, вариант предложенный @alll.